Why does maven-shade-plugin depend on spring-boot-maven-plugin in spring-boot-starter pom.xml?
w.r.t. this, I see that maven-shade-plugin depends on spring-boot-maven-plugin in spring-boot-starter pom.xml:
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
...
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.5</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

can someone explain why so and what is this trying to accomplish?

in order to make implementation org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer accessible for maven-shade-plugin
